# AJAX return to read php function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

im trying to echo the result of ajax;

my php code is

```
if(isset($_POST['date']) )
{
    echo "<input type='radio' id='date'/>";
}
```

and my ajax code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "schedule.php",
    data: {date:  dateAsString},
    success: function(result) 
    {
        $('#res').text(result); 
        // i know this is .text that's why printing text instead of html input. 
        // i don't know what line of code to execute my php into html command
    } 
});
```

how to echo the php line of code with html language to print input

Comment: Check your console for information. Have you defined an element with the id of `res` anywhere on that page? And if this is all that the JS is doing, you don't need AJAX or PHP - a simple JS append would work.

Comment: Do you have a tag somewhere with the res id  like `<span id="res"></span>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$('#res').text(result);
```

to

```
$('#res').html(result);
```